# Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS: autosuspend "cannot check the systems suspend ability"

Tags: server, 20.04, suspend, cron, hibernate

I'm quite new to Linux, so please be kind ;)

My project at the moment is a Nextcloud-Server running on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server. It is only for personal use for me and my SO ...so it doesn't need to run the whole day.
I searched the web for sth like a suspend-script and found this: [AutoSuspend-Script](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Archiv/Skripte/AutoSuspend/). It utilizes the *pm-utils* package, which as far as i know isn't in the current versions of Ubuntu anymore. But...:

It is kind of working, at least the cronjob runs... but most of the times it gives me the following error-log: "cannot check the systems suspend ability"
The second issue with all this is, that when the server is suspended it keeps waking up after a short amount of time and I can't see why. Is there any way to log this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had this script running flawless since 6 years on my private server, but since I've upgrade to 20.04 I'm expierencing issues with my suspend mode. I assume it is a different issue, but you could run into that one, too :)

For your problem:

- check chmod
- check if /usr/bin/pm-is-supported is responding, it causes your problem.

I assume you are missing some packages.